# Adyen, create token for credit card without making payment

Tags: payment, adyen

I know that a token can be created in Adyen for a credit card, when specifying `shopperReference` and `storePaymentMethod` to the payment request, together with the desired amount and currency. But I need to do that, without making an actual payment. So I need to save the card, get token for it and in the next step make the payment with that token.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a payment with the amount of 0. This will tokenize the card without actually charging the card. These zero dollar verifications flow is something established by visa/mc to make sure that card details can be verified vs tokenizing a fake or invalid card.

```
{
  "amount": {
    "currency": "USD",
    "value": 0
  },
  "reference": "Your order number",
  "paymentMethod": {
    "type": "scheme",
    "encryptedCardNumber": "test_4111111111111111",
    "encryptedExpiryMonth": "test_03",
    "encryptedExpiryYear": "test_2030",
    "encryptedSecurityCode": "test_737"
  },
  "merchantAccount": "YOUR_MERCHANT_ACCOUNT"
}
```

That said, not **all** banks support zero dollar verification but the vast majority of banks do. For banks that don't support it, Adyen will automatically perform a 1 dollar auth followed by an immediate cancel of that auth.